# Regex with a variable number of match groups

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I would like to be able to write *patterns* to recognize **filenames** in a list:

```
import re

NOTES = ["c", "c#", "d", "d#", "e", "f", "f#", "g", "g#", "a", "a#", "b"]

filelist1 = ["piano c3.wav", "piano c#3.wav", "piano d4.wav"]
pattern1 = "piano %notename.wav"

filelist2 = ["72__54.wav", "60__127.wav", "48__61.wav"]
pattern2 = "%midinote__%velocity.wav"
```

The keywords :

- `%midinote` and `%velocity` should be integers
- `%notename` should be a string like in the list `NOTES`

The following code works and parses the filenames, **but only if the 3 keywords are present in the pattern**, in the order %midinote, %velocity, %notename:

```
pattern1 = pattern1.replace("%midinote", r"(\d+)").replace("%velocity", r"(\d+)").replace("%notename", r"([A-Ga-g]#?[0-9])")
for fname in filelist1:
    m = re.match(pattern1, fname)
    if m:
        midinote = int(m.groups()[0])
        velocity = int(m.groups()[1])
        notename = m.groups()[2]
        notenametomidi = NOTES.index(notename[:-1].lower()) + (int(notename[-1])+2) * 12
        print fname, midinote, velocity, notename, notenametomidi
```

But if a pattern:

- has only 1 or 2 keywords
- or has the 3 keywords but in another order the the order defined before,

then the code fails.

**How to be able to regex with a *variable number* of match groups?**

Comment: Trying to replace midinote and velocity in pattern1 doesn't make sense, as it doesn't contain them.

Comment: @StefanPochmann My code should work for *any pattern* the user can write, containing zero, one, two or three of these keywords.

Comment: Sometime a pattern will contain three keywords, sometime a pattern will contain only 1 keyword, it should work anyway... I don't know how to handle that...

Comment: Cool story bro, but if I can't tell how your regex looks like, then I can't help.

Comment: You could also parse the given pattern for possible variable points (e.g. %midinote) and dynamically extract data from the groups based on this analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for are named capturing groups. Try this:

```
pattern1 = pattern1.replace("%midinote", r"(?P<midinote>\d+)").replace("%velocity", r"(?P<velocity>\d+)").replace("%notename", r"(?P<notename>[A-Ga-g]#?[0-9])")
for fname in filelist1:
    m = re.match(pattern1, fname)
    if m:
        info = m.groupdict()
        midinote = int(info.get('midinote',0))
        velocity = int(info.get('velocity',0))
        notename = info.get('notename', 'c')
        notenametomidi = NOTES.index(notename[:-1].lower()) + (int(notename[-1])+2) * 12
        print fname, midinote, velocity, notename, notenametomidi
```

Of course you have to change the standard values according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You want to be using named capture groups. Here are a couple functions that do it all, and some demo code:

```
# extract_midi_info.py

# For Python 2/3 compatibility
from __future__ import print_function

import re

NOTES = ("c", "c#", "d", "d#", "e", "f", "f#", "g", "g#", "a", "a#", "b")


def notename_to_midi(notename):
    return NOTES.index(notename[:-1].lower()) + (int(notename[-1])+2) * 12


def extract_midi_info(pattern, s):
    pattern = pattern.replace("%midinote", r"(?P<midinote>\d+)")
    pattern = pattern.replace("%velocity", r"(?P<velocity>\d+)")
    pattern = pattern.replace("%notename", r"(?P<notename>[A-Ga-g]#?[0-9])")

    m = re.match(pattern, s)

    if m:
        info = m.groupdict()
        if 'midinote' in info:
            info['midinote'] = int(info['midinote'])
        if 'velocity' in info:
            info['velocity'] = int(info['velocity'])
        if 'notename' in info:
            info['notename_midi'] = notename_to_midi(info['notename'])
    else:
        info = {}

    return info


def main():
    filelist_a = ["bonjour c3.wav", "bonjour c#3.wav", "bonjour d4.wav"]
    pattern_a = "bonjour %notename.wav"

    filelist_b = ["72__54.wav", "60__127.wav", "48__61.wav"]
    pattern_b = "%midinote__%velocity.wav"

    samples = [('A', filelist_a, pattern_a), ('B', filelist_b, pattern_b)]

    for name, filelist, pattern in samples:
        print()
        print('Filelist {0}'.format(name))
        for filename in filelist:
            info = extract_midi_info(pattern, filename)
            print(info)

    print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```